# Get the Current User in WebAPI2 with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Here's a bit of a back story, feel free to skip to the problem below.

We have a handful of web applications exposed to the outside world (as opposed to ONLY on our internal business network) and these applications are using HTML5 for the offline capabilities.  We also had IIS configured for Windows Authentication ONLY (no outside parties use our applications), thus we were issuing the challenge directly against our AD.  With a recent update to Chrome for iOS, it broke the NTLM authentication (instead of prompting for use credentials, it just displayed a 401 unauthorized exception page) so we started looking at alternative solutions.

We figured we could leverage our current external ADFS/O365 access thus the user experience would be the same across all external facing applications (not just web apps).

We ended up adding OWIN to our WebForms app to use ADFS authentication and it works from a perspective of you can see the redirect to our external login page and then back to the web app.  However, there is an additional problem.  To get this to work, we had to DISABLE Windows Authentication in IIS and ENABLE Anonymous Authentication.  Also, in the Web.Config in `<system.web>` we added `<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>`

PROBLEM

Since our applications are using HTML5 and are available offline, we are also using Web API to handle the push of data from the client device to the central system.  When we moved to our "SSO type" solution, the POST methods in Web API started crashing.  Turns out the line `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` stopped working.

How can I get the current authenticated [signed in] user when the user returns to the network and sync's their data?  I'm not even sure what the best approach is here, I've tried a few different suggestions from SO and Google, but none seem to work.  How does one get the current user in Web API with Owin using Federated Services?